# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $K$ be a dense subset of $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Given that $\{B_r(k)\}_{k \in K}$, is it true that $\{B_r(k)\}_{k \in K}$ is also open cover for $X$.

My goal is to show that $X \subseteq \cup_{k \in K}B_r(k)$. I know since $K$ is a dense subset of $X$, for all $x \in X$, either $x \in K$ or $x$ is limit point of K. The first case is easy but I am struggling with the second case.

Comment: $\cup_{k_K}$ - typo?

Comment: Yes, Corrected!!

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is a limit point of $K$, then in particular there is some $k \in K$ such that $d(x,k) < r$.  Then $x \in B_r(k)$.

Comment: Is it because of the fact that for all r > 0, $B_r(x)$ contains a point of $K \setminus \{x\}$?

Comment: @lyatit Yes (comment is too short to post)

Comment: $x \in X$ is in  the closure of $K$ iff for each $r> 0$ there exists $k \in K$ such that $d(x,k)< r$. This is equivalent to $x \in B_r(k)$. Thus $\bigcup_{k \in K} B_r(k)$ contains the closure of $K$. But $K$ is dense, thus its closure is $X$.